# run command in docker-compose.yml

Tags: mysql, laravel, docker, docker-compose

I have laravel project and must create a docker container for this.
I am done doing this but for MySQL I must run some commands

```
docker-compose exec app php artisan key:generate
docker-compose exec db bash
mysql -u root -p
Login Using password Library!23
GRANT ALL ON laravel.* TO 'root'@'%' IDENTIFIED BY '123';
FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
EXIT;
exit
docker-compose exec app php artisan migrate
```

In the line 2 app switch the bash and I must exit to run commands
but I need to open MySQL bash login and give permission to the user after that run artisan migrate
and its my docke-compose.yml

```
version: '3'
services:

  #PHP Service
  app:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    image: xxxxxxx/lumen:Library
    container_name: Library
    restart: unless-stopped
    tty: true
    environment:
      SERVICE_NAME: app
      SERVICE_TAGS: dev
    working_dir: /var/www
    volumes:
      - ./:/var/www
    networks:
      - app-network

  #Nginx Service
  webserver:
    image: nginx:alpine
    container_name: LibraryWebserver
    restart: unless-stopped
    tty: true
    ports:
      - "80:80"
      - "443:443"
    volumes:
      - ./:/var/www
      - ./nginx/conf.d/:/etc/nginx/conf.d/
    networks:
      - app-network

  #MySQL Service
  db:
    image: mysql:5.7.22
    container_name: Librarydb
    restart: unless-stopped
    tty: true
    ports:
      - "3306:3306"
    environment:
      MYSQL_DATABASE: library
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: Library!23
      SERVICE_TAGS: dev
      SERVICE_NAME: mysql
    networks:
      - app-network
    volumes:
      - dbdata:/var/lib/mysql
#Docker Networks
networks:
  app-network:
    driver: bridge
#Volumes
volumes:
  dbdata:
    driver: local
```

and my Dockerfile

```
FROM php:7.4-fpm

COPY composer.lock composer.json /var/www/

WORKDIR /var/www

RUN apt-get update --fix-missing && apt-get install -y  \
    build-essential \
    libssl-dev \
    zlib1g-dev \
    libpng-dev \
    libjpeg-dev \
    libfreetype6-dev \
    zlibc \
    mariadb-client \
    libpng-dev \
    libjpeg62-turbo-dev \
    libfreetype6-dev \
    locales \
    jpegoptim optipng pngquant gifsicle \
    vim \
    unzip \
    git \
    curl \
    zip

RUN docker-php-ext-install opcache  && docker-php-ext-enable opcache

RUN apt-get clean && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*

RUN docker-php-ext-install pdo_mysql exif pcntl
#RUN docker-php-ext-configure gd --with-gd --with-freetype-dir=/usr/include/ --with-jpeg-dir=/usr/include/ --with-png-dir=/usr/include/
RUN docker-php-ext-install bcmath

RUN curl -sS https://getcomposer.org/installer | php -- --install-dir=/usr/local/bin --filename=composer

EXPOSE 9000
CMD ["php-fpm"]
```

can anyone help me???
and i want to run `composer install` in app bash

Comment: second console ?

Comment: for exp:
im in hosein>laravel
after ```docker-compose exec db bash```
console goes to Docker>db

Comment: Why not write a single script to be run, which resides in the container?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

for step 2 - 8 you have to ways like our friends says
create bootstrap file with sql commands and run it in your dockerfile
or 
you can create user and pass and grant admin access to user in docker-compose.yml

```
 db:
    image: mysql:5.7.22
    container_name: Librarydb
    restart: unless-stopped
    tty: true
    ports:
      - "3306:3306"
    environment:
      MYSQL_DATABASE: library
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: TheRootPassword
      MYSQL_USER: root
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: PasswordForLoginAndUse
      SERVICE_TAGS: dev
      SERVICE_NAME: mysql
    networks:
      - app-network
    volumes:
      - dbdata:/var/lib/mysql
```

and about generating a key with artisan its not necessary
app think you run it in one system because of docker
and i prefer you to run migration manually 
its better

Answer (score 1):

instead of executing the MySQL commands directly (or manually). You can bootstrap MySQL containers with all the needed data and configurations using the following approach.

1- Create a bootstrap file : sql-scripts.sql

```
GRANT ALL ON laravel.* TO 'root'@'%' IDENTIFIED BY '123';
FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
```

2- Create a custom MySQL Docker image: mysql.Dockerfile

```
FROM mysql:8.0.1
COPY ./sql-scripts.sql /docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/
```

3- build MySQL docker image and use it in your docker-compose file. You need to before the below change on your docker-compose. The bootstrap file will be executed automatically the **FIRST TIME** you execute `docker-compose up`. you need to remove the MySQL volume to make this works for your stack `docker volume rm dbdata`.

```
db:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: mysql.Dockerfile
```

Comment: can you give me more help????
i copy script to docker-entrypoint-initdb.d and how to run it?

Comment: it will be executed automatically when you execute `docker-compose up`. can you share your compose file ?

Comment: im added my compose file

Comment: Please keep in mind that this script is usually only run when the container is started the very first time. If you need to re-run that script, you have to delete the attached volume first

Comment: hi again
dident work for me
```
mysql> SHOW DATABASES;
ERROR 1146 (42S02): Table 'information_schema.SCHEMATA' doesn't exist

```
if i run FROM : mysql:5.7.22 Its same error

Comment: can you share what you did exactly ?